# Problem converting Java applet to Jar. Maybe Image loading problem

Tags: java, image, jar, applet

I'm writing an applet in eclipse and under the eclipse environment it works well.

while creating a jar file from this project, the problems start.

After testing the jar with several options, I think the problem is with loading an image from a web page.

Any Other features from the applet seems to work ok in the jar.

The code of loading image in my project looks like that:

```
MediaTracker mt = new MediaTracker(this);
String photo = imagePath
URL base = null;
 try { 
 base = getDocumentBase(); 
 } 
 catch (Exception e) {
}
 if(base == null){
      System.out.println("ERROR LOADING IMAGE");
 }
 Image imageBase = getImage(base,photo); 
// Some code that works on the image (not relevant)

   // The rest of the code
    icon.setImage(image);
   imageLabel.setIcon(icon);
```

But the jar can not load the imgae and it doesn't disply it in while running and the applet is stuck because of that. (unlike in the eclipse, which loads the image and shows it)

What could be the problem?

A second problem is that from the applet in the eclipse the loading take few seconds. Is there a way to speed things up?

Thanks for any help,

Comment: can you post the error message, if you get one.

Comment: Welcome to SO, but.. what is this rubbish snippet above?  It would not even compile, let alone run.  For better help sooner, post an SSCCE (http://pscode.org/sscce.html).  Note also 2 things.  1)  getDocumentBase() does not throw exceptions.  2) the document base will never be null.

Comment: clamp: There are no error message. Andrew: the code I've upload is one of the options I've tested. The first code was used: ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(new URL(photo)). But I will glad to hear of better ways to load image from the web.  Regarding my problem I'm more thinking that the problem is with the loading time (even from the rather slow time in the eclipse). Using thread could solve some problems. (Not the time to load the Image though). I will try it and hope to resolve the problem. Thanks very much for the help, and will be happy to read more comments if there are. :)

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea how this could be working in Eclipse.

The problem is that getDocumentBase() returns location of a page, in which the applet is embedded (e.g. http://some.site.com/index.html), and you are trying to load a picture from that location. Obviously, there is no picture, just an html (or php) file, and the loading fails.

If your goal is to load an image from inside the jar, try:

```
Image img = null;
try {
    img = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/images/tree.png"));
} catch (IOException ex) {
    System.err.println("Picture loading failed!");
}
```

where "/images/tree.png" is path to image file in your source tree.

**EDIT**: If you need just to load an image from URL, you can use:

```
Image img = null;
try {
    img = ImageIO.read(new URL("http://some.site.com/images/tree.png"));
} catch (IOException ex) {
    System.err.println("Picture loading failed!");
}
```

This method is a bit better than Applet.getImage(new URL(...)) - I had some problems when loading many images.

Comment: I Hope this is the the right box. Thank you very much for the post. For your solution the problem occurs again. It is working perfectly fine in eclipse, but it is not loading through the jar file. (or it takes too long). I don't if it is relevant but from the applet as a jar I can connect to URL (other web page, for example, load "google.com" from the applet running as jar) and load and show them in another page (as I can do it from the eclipse), but I can't load the Image into Image object, unlike the eclipse case. Could it be due to security reasons?

Comment: If something is not working with my examples, then an exception will be thrown. You can see it if you will open your Java Console, - and it will probably give you a clue. And yes, if your applet is unsigned, then there are some security restrictions - I don't remember exactly, but there was something about allowing connections only to the host server.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the help. Well the problem was socket permission. I should add grant to the site I wish to connect to. I am reading about it, but would like to get other good pointers if you know of any. Thanks you all for the tips and help!